# JavaScript returning NaN variable returning undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, nan

I'm learning javascript at the moment, I have 2 problems with the same code.

1) The curly brackets if I place one on the top of the code under `var Character function`. I can get the `changedXPos();` command to work in the console, if I don't do that I get `changedXPos();`this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: changedXPos is not defined at :1:1" I'm not sure why.

2)In the `changedXPos` function when the code is run, I get the value as NaN. I have used the debugger and I can see that all instance of `xPos` is undefined. If I give `xPos = 20` the code works fine, so I know that the `xPos` for some reason is not behaving the way it should I'm just not sure why.

I have put comments in the code to show where the problem is.
Thank you for your time

```
var Character = function(name, xPos, yPos) {
  this.name = name;
  this.xPos = xPos;
  this.yPos = yPos;

  //} this bracket is not commentented out code works, by changedXPos(); in    console but xPos is still undefined

  //create instance of Character
  var ron = new Character("Ronald", 55, 30);
  var jil = new Character("Jill", 25, 45);
  var jas = new Character("Jasmine", 16, 85);

  //create arrary of instance Character
  var characterArray = [ron, jil, jas];

  //create for loop to loop through characterArray
  for (i = 0; i < characterArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(characterArray[i]);
  }

  this.information = function() {

    "My name is: " + this.name + " My X position is: " + this.xPos + " My Y  position is: " + this.yPos;
  }

  this.changedXPos = function(value) {
    // change the x position here
    //debugger;
    var xPos = this.xPos; // if i take this var out i get xPos is undefined 
    //var value = isNaN(parseInt(xPos)) ? 0 : parseInt(xPos);
    for (i = 0; i < characterArray.length; i++) {
      value = xPos + 20;
      console.log(value); // value is NaN or xPos is undefined
    }
  }

  this.changedYPos = function(value) {
    // change the y position here
  }

  Character.prototype.toString = function toString() {
    //var info = // character's name and current position on the screen
    //return info;
  };
} // with this bracket coded out above function is out of code block
```

Comment: Welcome.  Please read [ask], with a focus on _asking one question at a time_ (you are asking at least 2).  Please also read how to create an [mcve]

Comment: @warwick Do you want the `changedXPos, changedYPos` inside the constructor or outside? Can you please be little more clear on what you are trying to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is what you want to get your code fixed. To walk you over, you created constructor function Character, and then created 3 instances of it named `ron`, `jil`, and `jas`

Then you added bunch of functions on Character's prototype chain overriding toString method as well which prints out your custom method.

Runnable script on Stack overflow seems to print entire object but if you run it in code, it should work.

```js
function Character (name, xPos, yPos) {
  this.name = name;
  this.xPos = xPos;
  this.yPos = yPos;
}

var ron = new Character("Ronald", 55, 30);
var jil = new Character("Jill", 25, 45);
var jas = new Character("Jasmine", 16, 85);

var characterArray = [ron, jil, jas];

Character.prototype.changedXPos = function(value) {
  this.xPos = value;
}

Character.prototype.changedYPos = function(value) {
  this.yPos = value;
}

Character.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "My name is: " + this.name +
    " My X position is: " + this.xPos +
    " My Y  position is: " + this.yPos;
};

//create for loop to loop through characterArray
for (i = 0; i < characterArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(characterArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time your answer works as well now i can move on Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look at the below code and check if this is what you are trying to achieve.

```js
function Character(name, xPos, yPos) {
    this.name = name;
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;

    this.changedXPos = function(value) {
        this.xPos = this.xPos + value;
    }
    this.changedYPos = function(value) {
        this.yPos = this.yPos + value;
    }
    this.information = function() {
        return "My name is: " + this.name + " My X position is: " + this.xPos + " My Y  position is: " + this.yPos;       
    }
}

var ron = new Character("Ronald", 55, 30);
var jil = new Character("Jill", 25, 45);
var jas = new Character("Jasmine", 16, 85);
var characterArray =[ron,jil,jas];

function changedXPosition(value) {
    for(i = 0; i < characterArray.length; i++){
        characterArray[i].changedXPos(value);
    }
}

function changedYPosition(value){
    for(i = 0; i < characterArray.length; i++){
        characterArray[i].changedYPos(value);
    }
}

changedXPosition(20);
changedYPosition(30);

for(i = 0; i < characterArray.length; i++){
    console.log(characterArray[i].information());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer i think i know where i went wrong now. Its works fine.